# Delete TableViewCell then perform more actions

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, delegates

I am coding in **Swift**. I want to delete a `TableViewCell` by sliding from the right to left, but I want it *fast*, instant.
For now, I am performing more stuff than just removing the element from the `TableView`. Here is my code:

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {

        // Delete the row from the data source 
        myRecomBottlesArray[0].removeFromRecomm(myRecomBottlesArray[indexPath.row])
        myRecomBottlesArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}
```

As you can see, I do `myRecomBottlesArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)` and also `tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)` which are extremely fast.

My problem is that I am also doing `myRecomBottlesArray[0].removeFromRecomm(myRecomBottlesArray[indexPath.row])` which loads a table from memory, removes the element from that table, then saves the table again in memory.
So when I press on my `Delete` button there is a 2 seconds delay between the moment I press the button and the moment it actually removes the row in the GUI.

I would like to know how to first delete the row in the GUI and then only, in background, load my list, remove the element and saving the list again. This way, the user feels like it is instant and can continue to do stuff on the app when it is actually done in background.

I think I should use delegate but I am pretty new in this and I don't know how to do. I can provide more code if needed.

Here is the code for the `removeFromRecomm()` function:

```
var recomBottlesArray = NSMutableArray()    

func removeFromRecomm(bottle: Bottle) {
    let bottleLoaded = Bottle.loadSaved()
    bottleLoaded?.recomBottlesArray.removeObject(bottle)
    bottleLoaded?.save()
}

class func loadSaved() -> Bottle? {
    if let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("bottleList") as? NSData {
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? Bottle
    }
    return nil
}

func save() {
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "bottleList")
}
```

Comment: Does `removeFromRecomm` method do any operations on UI? Or it only updates the model?

Comment: It does no operation on the UI. It only touches the memory (`NSKeyedArchiver` more precisely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `removeFromRecomm` takes long to complete and blocks the main thread, that's the reason of the delay.

You can execute such a method in a background thread, using Grand Central Dispatch:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0), {
    myRecomBottlesArray[0].removeFromRecomm(myRecomBottlesArray[indexPath.row])
}
myRecomBottlesArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

There are also other ways to execute code in background, like `NSOperation`. You can read about them in [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). Be aware that UIKit is not thread-safe: all operations on UI objects have to be done in the main thread. Since your method `removeFromRecomm` operates only on model, it is safe to call it in a background thread,